# LinkExtractor - extract with condition

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy, captcha

I have a crawler that takes in urls and then follows the nextpage links for each url in the start urls and its working

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="pagnNext"]',)), callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),)
```

However as you can imagine I start getting captchas at some point for some urls. I've heard that there might be honeypots that are not visible for human but in the html code designed to make you click to identfy that you are a bot.

I wanna make the extractor extracts the link conditionally for example dont extract and click if  CSS style display:none exists or something like that

is this doable

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    if (response.css("thing i want to check exists"))
       return scrapy.Request(response.xpath('//a[@class="pagnNext"]'),
                             callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    # this would log http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    self.logger.info("Visited %s", response.url)
```

official docs:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

note: as for your captcha issue try messing with your settings. at least make sure your DOWNLOAD_DELAY is set to something other then 0. check out the other options https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html